# How do I keep `source .bashrc` from removing escapes in my alias command that has regex?

Tags: bash, alias

I use a batch-scheduled HPC/HTC system at work and it generates logs of submitted jobs that look like this: "submitted.job.o738523" or "submitted.job.e385723".

I used to have an alias command in my .bashrc to handily delete those files like this:
`alias rmlogs='rm *.[oe]* && rm *.p[oe]*'`
The addition of the "p" before [oe] is for a workflow program that makes pending job logs.
Unfortunately, that could delete important things like "setup.exe" so I wanted something more specific

After much trial and tribulation I came up with this alias:
`alias rmlogs='find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f -regextype sed -regex '.\+\.[p]*[oe]\+[0-9]\+' -delete'`

Which I tested to work.

Unfortunately, when I start a new shell and .bashrc is sourced, the rmlogs command turns into this:
`alias rmlogs='find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f -regextype sed -regex .+.[p]*[oe]+[0-9]+ -delete'`

Which doesn't delete those pesky log files.

So what I'm asking: is there a way to get alias to keep the command as-is?

Or, alternately, is there another way to find and delete these pesky files (maybe with a function)?

Comment: You can't nest simple quotes. Use `alias rmlogs='find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f -regextype sed -regex ".\+\.[p]*[oe]\+[0-9]\+" -delete'` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost always want to use a function in preference to an alias:

```
rmlogs () {
  find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f -regextype sed -regex '.+.[p]*[oe]+[0-9]+' -delete
}
```

This avoids an entire level of quoting in addition to other problems (like not being able to provide arguments to an alias).

Comment: Thanks! This worked with a minor edit: I still had to have escapes in the regex like so: `rmlogs () { find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f -regextype sed -regex '.\+\.[p]*[oe]\+[0-9]\+' -delete }`